# How do I fetch a 404 response from OwlBot API in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I am writing a simple dictionary app in flutter using [owlbot](https://owlbot.info/api-reference#tag/English-Dictionary)API. I have managed to do the better part of it but cannot capture 404 message that is displayed in case somebody searches a non-english word. This is the response I get in case I search a non english word.

```
I/flutter ( 2747): [{message: No definition :(}]
```

I am using the following code to capture the response but am getting the error
**type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'**

```
if (!snapshot.data) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("Enter a valid word"),
          );
        }
```

How do I capture the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `snapshot` is an [AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) the [data](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html) property is the latest data received by the asynchronous computation. The type of the `snapshot.data` is probably not a bool in your case and can therefore not be evaluated in the if condition.

If you want to check if your `snapshot` contains non-null data you can access the `snapshot.hasData` property.